# JPA 2: how to declare primary-key columns in @ElementCollection tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0

in JPA2 when we are using Embed-able (Basic Type like String.. etc ) object in Entity using with @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable annotation , the new table is created , but in new table how to declare primary-key contraint in column ? following is my code

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name; 
private String salary;
@Transient
private String phnNum;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EmployeeType type;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="vacations" , joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Emp_Id"))
private Collection<Vacation> vacationBooking;

@ElementCollection
private Set<String> nickNames;

    ...................
```

with this code the "vacation" and "employee_nickname" two tables are created in schema. but i want to declare the one primary-key column in both table . what i do for this?

Comment: Can you put the complete code, including the code for Vacation class?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a primary key *per se* is not supported by JPA 2.0:

> From [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Primary_keys_in_CollectionTable):
>
> The JPA 2.0 specification does not provide a way to define the Id in the Embeddable. However, to delete or update an element of the ElementCollection mapping, some unique key is normally required. Otherwise, on every update the JPA provider would need to delete everything from the CollectionTable for the Entity, and then insert the values back. So, the JPA provider will most likely assume that the combination of all of the fields in the Embeddable are unique, in combination with the foreign key (JoinColumn(s)). This however could be inefficient, or just not feasible if the Embeddable is big, or complex.
>
> Some JPA providers may allow the Id to be specified in the Embeddable, to resolve this issue. Note in this case the Id only needs to be unique for the collection, not the table, as the foreign key is included. Some may also allow the unique option on the CollectionTable to be used for this. Otherwise, if your Embeddable is complex, you may consider making it an Entity and use a OneToMany instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to assign 'id' from Employee table as foreign key to the Vacation table?
In that case, you should use @OneToMany instead of @ElementCollection

Comment: No ,with this code the two tables are created vacations and nickNames , these tables are created at run time. in these tables there is no primary-key column . i want to declare primary-key column in this tables.

Comment: you put the complete code. and do mention if you already have a primary key attribute in vacation class, or do you want to create a surrogate primary key. without the code, its difficult to understand what you want. And just to remind you, tables created by hibernate always have a primary key. Hibernate is ORM tool. R is for "Relational", and without a primary key, there is no "R" :)

Comment: He meant a primary key on table `vacations`. Like `PK(Emp_Id, vacationBooking)`.